# What is the difference between "the law" and "the commandment" given by God to Moses? (Exodus 24:12)

Tags: hebrew, exodus, law

Exodus 24:12:

> The LORD said to Moses, "Come up to me on the mountain and wait there, that I may give you the tablets of stone, with the law and the commandment, which I have written for their instruction." (ESV)

What is the difference between "the law" and "the commandment" given by God to Moses?

Comment: Anyone else have anything?

Answer (score 1):

Translations always provide issues. What it says in a less directly-translated manner is "the Torah and commandment".

Tracing back to the original:
 'The Law' = תורה = 'the Torah'
 'The Commandment' = מצוה = 'commandments'

The meaning then is that all of the 613 commandments in the Torah (the Law), derive from the ten commandment in some manner, according to the medieval Jewish commentator Rashi.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  When you have a chance, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on  how this site is [a little different](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives#803) than other sites around the web. *This is not a comment on the quality of your answer, but rather a standard welcome message.*